# Char not adding to my string when i println?

Tags: java, string, methods, char

I am in the process of making a method presentParticiple that returns the present participle of a word EnglishWord.

When I run the program and the EnglishWord ends with a consonant (The 2nd if-statement), the char that I declare is not added. What did I do wrong?

```
private String ending1 = ".*[b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z]e";
private String consonant = ".*[b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z]";

public void run() {
    presentParticiple("jam");           
}

private String presentParticiple(String EnglishWord) {
    String correctWord = "";
    if (EnglishWord.endsWith(ending1)) {
        correctWord = EnglishWord.substring(0,EnglishWord.length()-1)+"ing";
    }

    else if (EnglishWord.endsWith(consonant)) {
        char ch = EnglishWord.charAt(EnglishWord.length());
        correctWord = EnglishWord.substring(0, EnglishWord.length())+ch+"ing";


    } else {
        correctWord = EnglishWord+"ing";
    }
    println(correctWord);
    return correctWord;
}
```

Comment: Last character in a `String` has index `length() - 1`.

Comment: Indexes in Java is in most cases start from 0 which means that last index will be `lengt - 1`.

Comment: Also `endsWith` doesn't use regex (and character class `[...]` doesn't need any separator like `,`, so simply write `.*[bcdfg...]` or use intersection of sets to eliminate characters you don't want in range `a-z`)

Comment: Also, variables start with a lowercase letter. Names with uppercase first letters are typically used for class names. So, "EnglishWord" becomes "englishWord".

Comment: @Pshemo What do you mean with regex?

Comment: By regex i mean regular expression. I assumed that your string was supposed to represent one since you used `.*` and `[...]` which are part of regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works (incorporating the suggestions above).

```
public class EnglishTest
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String[] words = { "jam", "rue", "raze", "knock", "need" };
    for (String word : words)
      presentParticiple (word);
  }

  private static final String ending1 = ".*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]e";
  private static final String consonant = ".*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]";

  private static String presentParticiple (String englishWord)
  {
    String correctWord = "";
    if (englishWord.matches (ending1))
      correctWord = englishWord.substring (0, englishWord.length () - 1) + "ing";
    else if (englishWord.matches (consonant))
    {
      char ch = englishWord.charAt (englishWord.length () - 1);
      correctWord = englishWord + ch + "ing";
    }
    else
      correctWord = englishWord + "ing";

    System.out.println (correctWord);
    return correctWord;
  }
}
```

Your algorithm has problems though. Try 'knock' for example.

Comment: Yeah I see it works, but doesn't the matches-method return true if there is a consonant anywhere in the word?

Comment: Try it now, 'rue' and 'raze' give different results.